# Embedding videos other than you-tube videos is not coming in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have embedded YouTube videos in my application and they are working fine .But when I tried to embed Google videos into my application , blank screen appears.
I would like to know the reason.

Comment: does your videos are working fine in safari???

Comment: yes ,in safari they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Google videos uses flash which the iPhone does not support. If would like to load a non YouTube video, set the URL to a plain mp4 file.